# Pass TextInput props between different screens in React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am totally lost on how to grab two parameters from a form screen and pass them via React Navigator and display them on the previous screen.

The app section in question works like this: 

1. touchablehighlight to form screen.

2. input title and description and press submit onpress

3. the onpress runs a function that dispatches the parameters to the previous page via a key.

4. then returns back to the origin page, with the props on display.

I am having multiple issues with the process:

1. if I am understanding the docs correctly, each page has a unique key and i tried to find it via this.props.navigation.state.key, however unknown to me, on refresh the id number would change.

2. that leads to problem 2 where the function will run, but it will not redirect back to the original page.

3. i have tried .navigate line after .dispatch but it would open a new copy of the original page and not display the new props that supposively were passed down.

```js
import React from 'react';
import styles from '../styling/style.js';
import { Text, View, Image, TouchableHighlight, TextInput, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import Forms from './formGenerator';

export default class Workout extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
     programTitle: '',
     programDescription: ''
  }
}

render() {
  const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
  return (    
    <Image style={styles.workoutContainer, { flex: 1}} source={require("../images/HomepageBackground.jpg")}>
      <View style={styles.workoutBody}>
          <Text style={styles.workoutTextBody}> {this.state.programTitle}</Text> 
          <Text style={styles.workoutTextBody}>{this.state.programDescription}</Text>
      </View>
        <View style={styles.createButton}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={Alert.alert(this.props.navigation.state.key)} style={styles.addButtonTouch} title='test' >
         <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>+</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    </Image>    
    );
  }

// End of the render
}
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import styles from '../styling/style.js';
import { Text, View, Image, TouchableHighlight, TextInput, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import Workout from './workouts';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';


export default class Forms extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
     programTitle: '',
     programDescription: ''
  }
}

render() {
  const {goBack} = this.props.navigation;
  const {params} = this.props.navigation.state;
  return (    
    <Image style={styles.workoutContainer, { flex: 1}} source={require("../images/HomepageBackground.jpg")}>
      <View style={styles.workoutBody}>
        <Text style={styles.formHeader}>Program Title</Text>
          <TextInput
            autoFocus={true}
            style={styles.formBody}
            onChangeText={(programTitle) => this.setState({programTitle})}
            placeholder='Title'
            value={this.state.programTitle} />
        <Text style={styles.formHeader}>Description (Ex. 4sets x 10reps)</Text>
          <TextInput
            autoFocus={true}
            style={styles.formBody}
            placeholder='Description'
            onChangeText={(programDescription) => this.setState({programDescription})}
            value={this.state.programDescription} />
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.addProgram} style={styles.buttonBody} title="Add Program" >
          <Text>Add Program</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>  
      </View>
    </Image>    
    );
  }

addProgram = () => {
  Alert.alert(this.props.navigation.state.key);
  this.setState({programTitle: ''});
  this.setState({programDescription: ''});
  const setParamsAction = NavigationActions.setParams({
  params: { programTitle: this.state.programTitle, programDescription: this.state.programDescription },
  key: ,
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(setParamsAction)
};

}
```

Comment: sorry, am not getting you.. which one you are referring to the current screen and previous screen?

Comment: @JefreeSujit sorry it would be like this firstpage(onpress) >formpage(onpress) > back to the orginal firstpage w/ updated states

Comment: i would suggest you to use callbacks instead of using page key. Pass a callback as props to formpage and onSubmit return false and pass the values to parent callback, and let the parent submits the value. By this way the firstpage can retain the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get parameter from "Next Page", you could have two approaches.

1, save the params in AsyncStorage (suggested)

2, using navigation setParams function with the params

```
const setParamsAction = NavigationActions.setParams({
  params: { title: 'Hello' },
  key: 'screen-123',
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(setParamsAction)
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions

Answer (score 0):

You are just trying to display information from the `Forms` class on the `Workout class`, correct??

From your `Workout` class, create a function that update's it's state.

```
updateWorkoutState = (programTitle,programDescription) => this.setState(programTitle,programDescription)
```

Pass that function through to the `Forms` class when you push that route.

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate('Forms',{updateWorkoutState: this.updateWorkoutState}
```

Once your conditions are met on the `Forms` class and you want to update the `Workout` component, call it with `this.props.navigation.state.params.updateWorkoutState(val1,val2)`

Do not use `AsyncStorage` for this.